# Can't find Web Form item in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I can't seem to find a Web Form item when adding trying to add a new item in my ASP.NET web application project in Visual studio 17.0.1. Any help?

[image: add item picture]

Comment: How are you adding the new item?

Comment: @AndrewMorton right clicking on the web application folder then selceting add new item, but i can't find it in the web and c# visual sections

Comment: I can take no credit for this solution: [Visual Studio : How to fix missing ASP.NET template for .NET Framework](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2021/11/visual-studio-missing-asp-net-web-application-template-dotnet-framework/). Basically, add the individual component ".NET Framework project and item templates" in Visual Studio Installer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was solved by modifying the installation in Visual Studio Installer and installing the ".NET Framework project and item templates" component under the "Individual components" tab.

Credits to:
https://www.howtosolutions.net/2021/11/visual-studio-missing-asp-net-web-application-template-dotnet-framework/

Answer (score 3):

I saw this problem in "Visual Studio 2022 preview" too. It was solved by modifying and installing the ".NET Framework project and item templates" (in Visual Studio Installer):

[image: like this]